# Using Android Search Interface for searching stored SMS Messages

Tags: android, sms

As a College Project, I have to create an Android App for searching the SMS Messages stored in the device. for eg. if one types "hi", then all the messages containing the word "hi" are displayed on screen.
I know that this is directly possible in the new Android versions but now I can't change the topic and I'll have create such an app and complete it in 1st week of January 2012!

I have searched on Google and have found 2 ways:-

1. Using the [Mobdev Wiki Tutorial](http://mobdev.olin.edu/mobdevwiki/FrontPage/Tutorials/SMS%20Messaging) and searching for the messages, which is complex and I have not yet used databases for programming so it is fairly new for me.
2. Using the [Android Search Interface](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html) for directly using Android's search UI and make things easier and simpler for me.

I need suggestions on which method is suitable and what other options are available. And how can the SMS Database be linked to the Android Search Interface and the messages be displayed properly on screen. Looking forward to your suggestions and answers, if you don't have time, please atleast give links to useful resources related to the above problem!

Comment: first you should understand android platform and content providers ... 1st week of January 2012  ... hmmm, so what did you do last 6 mths? good luck anyway

Comment: @selvin I started in August 2011 and read the first few hundred pages of [The Busy Coder's Guide to Android Development](http://commonsware.com/Android/) and have idea about the platform and have learnt about using XML and Java for Android and can even make a small app on my own now, then I went on to their 2nd book, Android Programming Tutorials and did many chapters from it, but sadly, none of the books have any chapters related to my problem about stored SMS Messages, so need help on this specific problem...:-)

Comment: all u need to do is "ask" sms ContentProvider about this messages ... this special contentprovider is just abstract for underlaying SQLite database with sms ... `context.getContentResolver().query(smsUriInboxOrOutboxOrWhatever, new String[] {columns, to, show}, SearchColumn + ' LIKE ?', new String[] {searchText}, null)` ... it will return Cursor ... now you have to show all data from this Cursor ...

Comment: @Selvin I'll read the chapters on ContentProvider and Cursors again and then hopefully I'll be able to understand the above code nicely soon! Thanks A Lot!!

Comment: anway i had no time to read all this stuff but ... http://mobdev.olin.edu/mobdevwiki/FrontPage/Tutorials/SMS%20Messaging#open_a_cursor here is exacly what i wrote ... but this code returns all sms and you need to search .... that's why selection and selectionArgs shouldn't be null ... android search interface ... well .... it's too complicated for ya ... coz you need to build your own ContentProvider ...

Comment: Thats Y I m thinking of making use of the 2nd method that I wrote in my original post and also in d title of this question, if I m able to make this app using the Android Search Interface then it would b much simpler to implement and use for me at this level, any suggestions please???
Please can any1 giv any suggestions on searching Messages using the [Android Search Interface](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html)

Comment: @Selvin sorry i just read the 2nd part of your comment now, it won't be complicated to use Android Search Interface if I get someone else's ContentProvider or if sm1 would could paste its code here if its not too big.

Comment: Is this the place where I should look for understanding the method used on mobdev wiki's tutorial:-
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html

Answer (score 1):

Use a Editbox and a search button as a GUI.
And the main code for searching a particular word in Inbox is::

```
static Uri uri ;
Cursor c;
uri = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
c = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null ,null, "date DESC");
startManagingCursor(c);

String[] body = new String[c.getCount()];

if(c.moveToFirst()){
for(int i=0;i<c.getCount();i++){
    body[i]= c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body")); //.toString()

    item = check(body[i]);

    c.moveToNext();
}
}
c.close();
```

While the check function is::

```
public ArrayList<String> check(String str)
{

    boolean fullContainsSub = str.toUpperCase().indexOf(content.toUpperCase()) != -1;

    if(fullContainsSub)
    {
     itemList.add(str);
    }
    return itemList;
}
```

Hope this helps others !!!